# edge.js - unable to run parameterized query where parameter has null value

Tags: edge.js

I'm attempting to write data into SQL Server from a Node.js app, using edge.js. The data in question has a certain amount of variability, such that certain properties are often undefined. These are optional values, and are represented as such in the database e.g. `referrer (nvarchar(255), null)`.

When processing the data, I map it to a pre-defined model class, and explicitly set `undefined` properties to `null`. This ensures that all the parameters that the query requires are present. However, when I run the query, edge.js errors complaining that the parameter is not supplied. If I change the `null` value to be empty string, it works, but this obviously not desirable. Example code ...

```
var edge = require('edge');

// entity to save
var Visit = function Visit(obj) {
  obj = obj || {};

  this.eventtype = 'Visit';
  this.visitguid = obj.visitguid;
  this.url = obj.url || null;
  this.useragent = obj.useragent || null;
  this.referrer = obj.referrer || null;
  this.created = obj.created || null;

  return this;
}

var insertVisit = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
  INSERT INTO Visits (guid, url, useragent, referrer, created)
  VALUES
    (@visitguid
    ,@url
    ,@useragent
    ,@referrer
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME, @created, 103))
*/});

var visit = new Visit({
  visitguid: 'f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479',
  url: 'www.a-website.com/page/',
  useragent: 'Googlebot',
  created: '13/06/2014 12:41.000'
});

insertVisit(visit, function (err, result) { /* callback code here */ });
```

The error thrown is

```
error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The parameterized query '(@eventtype nvarchar(28),@visitguid nvarchar(36),@url nvarchar(3' expects the parameter '@referrer', which was not supplied.
```

I presume this is a problem/limitation in edge.js. For example, in C# you would set a `null` parameter to `DBNull.Value` rather than `null` straight up, but there's no obvious or documented way to achieve this in JavaScript. Is there any way to make this work?

(Of course, I could use edge to write out some C# code to do the DB write, but that'll be a bit more involved, so I'd prefer to do it like above if possible.)

Any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in edge-sql v0.1.2 (which also adds support for calling stored procedures in addition to basic CRUD operations).

Comment: Confirmed. Thanks very much Tomasz.